# Scatter plot points subset colour shape ifelse

Tags: r, plot, subset, point

I'd like to do a scatter plot where some of the values, out of a subset, are plotted differently in colour and shape.
I've worked around the following code but I don't manage to make it right.
Any help greatly appreciated!

```
# My data
iris
iris$Code <- 1:150

# A selection of my data I'd like to plot differently
subset <- subset(iris, iris$Sepal.Width<3.5)
sel <- as.character(subset$Code) # I think the problems start here :)

# Plotting doesn't work
plot(iris$Sepal.Length ~ iris$Sepal.Width,
     col=ifelse(iris$Code==sel, "red", "black"),
     pch=ifelse(iris$Code==sel, 17, 1))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
#define subset
sel <- iris[iris$Sepal.Width<3.5,"Code"]
#plot
plot(iris$Sepal.Length ~ iris$Sepal.Width,
     col=ifelse(iris$Code %in% sel, "red", "black"),
     pch=ifelse(iris$Code %in% sel, 17, 1))
```

**Note:** in your code there are some obvious mistakes:

`dd <- iris` - why assign to `dd` and never use it?

`iris$Sepal.Widith` - spelling

`... "black")` - comma missing at the end.

Comment: Thanks a lot zx8754, it works great! Yes, I had I few mistakes, sorry about that! I think I wrote the question too quickly! I've just edited my post.